# How can I change the size of the text?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bios, vga

I have this code in assembly x8086. I want in to print text while graphic mode; do you know how can I change the size of it?

```
mov  dh, 12   ;Row
mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
mov  ah, 02h  ;SetCursorPosition
int  10h

mov  al, 'x'
mov  bl, 0Ch  ;Color is red
mov  bh, 0    ;Display page
mov  ah, 0Eh  ;Teletype
int  10h
```

Comment: The BIOS only supports one size text.  If you want to print text in other sizes, you have to program that yourself.

Comment: it has been decades, but you are in a text mode, the font is like 8x8 pixels although I want to remember there might have been 8x16 or something.  vesa added more stuff, but it may just be a higher resolution with the same sized font.  I am sure you have BIOS call reference documentation if you are working at this level so look through the calls to see what is available, I also believe it really is just the one font size, although possibly more than one video mode (dimensions and colors), but would have to find my docs and that is beyond what SO is about...

Answer (score -1):

Although there's no resizing text in a "modern" sense, the easiest way is to use

```
mov ax,13h
int 10h
```

because the text in this mode is larger than your typical teletype. You can still use the same DOS `int`errupts for printing text to the screen.

Comment: What does that BIOS call do?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H says int 10h with AH=13h is a `write_string` call that takes args in multiple other registers.

Comment: That was a typo, it was supposed to be `mov ax, 13h`, to change to VGA mode 13h